# Wrapfigure and tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, wrapfigure

I would like to put a tcolorbox into a wrapfigure, like this:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
    \vspace{-8mm}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\linewidth,
        colback=cyan!10!white,
        colframe=white,
        colbacktitle=cyan!30!white,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        coltitle=black!20!black,
        title= \vspace{1mm}My title,
        titlerule=1mm,
        titlerule style=cyan
        segmentation style={cyan, line width=1.5pt, solid}
        ]
        Just some text, but the titlerule is not working :(
        \tcblower
        More text, but the segmentation style is not working neither.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Unfortunately the titlerule is not working (I only get a white titlerule). Can please someone explain to me why?

I also tried this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, xcolor=dvipsnames]{scrartcl}
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}             
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\linewidth,
            %enhanced jigsaw,
            colback=cyan!10!white,
            colframe=white,
            colbacktitle=cyan!30!white,
            fonttitle=\bfseries,
            coltitle=black!20!black,
            title= \vspace{1mm}My title,
            titlerule=3mm,
            titlerule style=red,
            segmentation style={cyan, line width=1.5pt, solid}
            ]
            Just some text, but the titlerule is not working :(
            \tcblower
            More text, but the segmentation style is not working neither.
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{wrapfigure}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

But `titlerule style` and `segmentation style` is still not working ....

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should add a comma after `titlerule style=cyan`. I think, this has nothing to do with placing the `tcolorbox` in a `wrapfigure`, though

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but unfortunately it is still not working ...
(I already had a comma there, but it got lost, when i copied it)

Comment: Then, I fear, you need to tell more about your setup. Consider providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows your problem. I cannot reproduce the problem with just the snippet you posted so far.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I edited my question ;)

Comment: You need to add `\tcbuselibrary{skins}` (placed after `\usepackage{tcolorbox}`) to load the `skins` library without which you cannot use `titlerule style` and `segmentation style`.

Comment: Thanks, the MWE is now working, but the example i placed in the first place still does not work. Do you know why?

Comment: Is it possible that something overwrites ```\tcbuselibrary{skins}```?

Comment: Well thank you, I will try to find my mistake. Unfortunately my code is too long to post here

Comment: Yeah, you are totally right, I just got it myself. Sorry for the time I cost you, this was just stupid of me, I am sorry. But you helped me a lot and also calmed me down a lot, otherwise I would have gone completly crazy. Thanks for your support!

Comment: No it is fine. Sorry that I did not see this from the beginning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you should add to your code to make the options `titlerule style` and `segmentation style` usable: 1) You need to add `\tcbuselibrary{skins}` to your preamble and 2) you need to add `enhanced` to the styling options.

So, the full code should look like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        width=\linewidth,
        enhanced,
        colback=cyan!10!white,
        colframe=white,
        colbacktitle=cyan!30!white,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        coltitle=black!20!black,
        title={\vspace{1mm}My title},
        titlerule=3mm,
        titlerule style=cyan,
        segmentation style={cyan, line width=1.5pt, solid}
    ]
        Just some text, now the titlerule is working :)
        \tcblower
        More text, and the segmentation style is also working.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{wrapfigure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Sorry, I first did not spot the problem in your code!

Comment: Now it works fine, thank you!
By any chance do you know wheater it is possible to make this ``` tcolorbox``` in the ``` wrapfigure``` environment ```breakable ```? But I honestly fear that this is going to be tricky?

Comment: Breakable inside the `wrapfigure`? So it should span multiple pages? Someone tried this before: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/622073/47927 ...

Comment: Yes, exactly that is what I was looking for, thanks for the link!

Comment: Btw, your reputation score is really impressive I only realised it now!

Comment: Actually, breakable `tcolorbox`es are sometimes a bit tricky to handle. I fear, handling them correctly inside the `wrapfigure` environment is probably not too easy. The answer in the linked thread uses some other approach with columns, but maybe this also works for you? You may want to ask a new question about this.

Comment: Well, this sounds like a challenge for another day ^^, but I will try, unfortunately my latex skills are not too good at the time

Comment: Actually, I don't know that much about `tcolorbox`es ... My score is rather a result from me having been on this site already for some time.